# Spring - Create scheudled tasks from external files

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-scheduled

I have a spring boot application that reads configuration files from storage.
I want that for each file - a scheduled task will be created.
The files are read and stored into a Pojo `MyFileData` and i have a bean that returns `List<MyFileData>` 
I have read about `SchedulingConfigurer` but I don't understand how i can get the bean value inside the `configureTasks` method.

```
@Configuration
public class FirstConfigFile {
    
    @Bean
    public List<MyFileData> myFileDataList() {
        List<MyFileData> myConfigFiles = new ArrayList();
        // read from storage
        return myConfigFiles;
    }

}

@Configuration
public class SecondConfigFile implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        // how do i get the myFileDataList bean?
        for(MyFileData fd : myFileDataList) {
            // create scheduled tasks and regiester them in the taskRegistrar
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I prefer to keep the `@Configuration` classes separate.

Answer (score 0):

You can @Autowired that List as it is declared as @Bean.